# Manuplate Excel file with OLEDB, with file streams instead of physical file

Tags: c#, excel-2003

Earlier I was reading excel file located on file system through Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0, and that was working fine, But now my client has told me that place excel file into a database table as BLOB column and read that file from that column and hide one workbook by manipulating that memory string directly.

Please help me out from this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Create a temp with the BLOB contents and replace the BLOB when done.

```
string fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
  stream.Write(blobContents);

// open excel with oledb
// and do your processing

using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{
   var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
   stream.Read(buffer, 0, stream.Length);

   //save blob
}
```